# Bootstrap Large Drawer Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to emulate a neat menu system I saw on telerik's website using `bootstrap`. You can see the example of what I want to achieve here:

## [telerik.com](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/panelbar/index.html)

Load this page and click on **Products**, and you will see a large "drawer" drop down. I love this effect.

I want to do this with bootstrap, but I am finding it difficult. This is the typical code used to make a dropdown menu item in bootstrap...

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So I am a bit confused about the approach to take here; How can I get the drop down area to span the entire screen? And then beyond that, how can I allow the user to click on parts of the dropped down layer without closing the actual menu?

I would really appreciate any help here, I am new to bootstrap and this is for some reason frustrating me a lot.

## UPDATE

I have managed to come close to my goal. I have an example here; ***The problem now is that I am not sure how to make the javascript edit on bootsnipp so I can share it with everyone.***

## [Bootstrap Large Drawer Sample](http://bootsnipp.com/fullscreen/Vn23)

I made the following changes; please note, I am using bootstrap's **less** files, not the compiled css.

## dropdowns.less

```
// The dropdown menu (ul)
.dropdown-menu {
    // no changes made to this class, but a new attachable class added below
        
        // added this companion class to give the effect I want
    &.drawer {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Then I made the following edit to the bootstrap.js at around `line 488`

## bootstrap.js

```
function clearMenus(e) {
    if (e) if ($(e.target).parents().hasClass('open')) return; // this is the added line

    // the rest was left alone
}
```

Now then, with that added I can do the following;

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a id="drop1" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu drawer" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
                </p>
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                    <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                </div><!--/row-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" id="drop2" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://twitter.com/fat">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://twitter.com/fat">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://twitter.com/fat">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://twitter.com/fat">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

I want to post this on bootsnipp, but I cannot figure out how to do the actual javascript part properly there. If anyone wants to show me how, I will award them the points.

The answer to this question required two extremely small edits to the bootstrap system.

I made the following changes; please note, I am using bootstrap's **less** files, not the compiled css. This can also be done to the native .css by adding the class `.dropdown-menu.drawer`

## dropdowns.less

```
// The dropdown menu (ul)
.dropdown-menu {
    // no changes made to this class, but a new attachable class added below
        
        // added this companion class to give the effect I want
    &.drawer {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Then the trick is to make sure that clicking on the drawer itself, or content in it, does not close the drawer. This was the hard part. To fix it, I edited a line in `bootstrap.js`.

Starting at line `488` in `bootstrap.js`, or around there, you want to make the following change to `function clearMenus(e)`.

## bootstrap.js

```
function clearMenus(e) {
    if (e) if ($(e.target).parents().hasClass('open')) return; // this is the added line

    // the rest was left alone
}
```

Then, I can affix the class `drawer` to the element I want to drop down.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a id="drop1" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu drawer" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
                </p>
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                    <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                </div><!--/row-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" id="drop2" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://twitter.com/fat">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://twitter.com/fat">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://twitter.com/fat">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://twitter.com/fat">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an example of what you are looking for:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/nav-account-manager

Comment: Hey, this is close, but not quite similar. I have posted updates to my code above, and am nearing an answer. I just have to solve the javascript part now. Any help is appreciated. Here is a link to the project. http://bootsnipp.com/fullscreen/Vn23

Comment: I think you would have to override the Dropdown.prototype.keydown to not close the dialog

Comment: I do not think that has anything to do with it. The actual behavior is happening in the `clearMenus` function, I just cannot figure out how to tell it to ignore the function if the user is clicking on the open dialog, or any part of the open dialog.

Comment: Alright, I have fixed it I think; Though I am unsure of how to show the fix in bootsnipp. Is there a way to include edits to the bootstrap .js file?

Comment: You are right the keydown is not for the mouse clicks clearly. Perhaps it gets dismissed on blur?

Comment: Well no, the issue turned out to be on line 488 of the `bootstrap.js` file. I have a fix, I just cannot figure out how to modify the bootstrap stuff on bootsnipp. I'll post the fix here on stack overflow though

Comment: Alright, I updated the post with the fix. I just have to figure out how to get it onto bootsnipp so I can share it with everyone.